# Custom navigation bar for the "More" View Controller in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

With the code below (for lower versions of iOS) I am subclassing `UINavigationBar` and applying to each navigation bar (of each navigation controller) in my `UITabBarController`.

```
@implementation CustomNavigationBar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customNavigationBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

The code works fine for the view controllers that are visibly accessible, but when pressing the "More" tab to access the other view controllers, the custom image does not appear any more. Have I missed something?

Comment: Do the more dots appear . . .  ?? Please show how you are initialising your UITabBarController....

Comment: Yes they appear, the `UITabController` is initialised in Interface Builder and handled in my main view controller. The More dots do appear, and I've no problem with the controller itself, just the customisation. All view controller's are customised apart from those that are contained in the 'More ..." tab.

Comment: How many view controllers are in the UITabBarController? I'm guessing more than 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I customise the More View Controller is to ensure that you don't get the default more controller from the UITabBarController itself - which is what sounds like you are experiencing.

1 Create your own More view controller. It will have its own custom icon

```
//MyMoreViewController.m
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"More", @"More");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyCustomMoreImage"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and then

2 When you initialise your UITabBarController, ensure you send five *exactly* view controllers to the initialiser AND that your custom more view controller is the root view controller of the 5th item - i.e. commonly you would use a navigation controller with your more view controller being set to it's rootViewController.

Comment: The only issue I have with this method is that I lose the ability to re-order the tabs in "Edit" mode. I may have to settle with a tint color.

Comment: Its a good point - I sacrificed the re-ordering in favour of being able to NOT have the default uitableview look and feel and was happy with that. If you want/need the re-ordering then you either can't do it this way OR have to re-invent it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The `UITabBarController` will create the `UINavigationController` for the More item, so its `UINavigationBar` won't be an instance of your class, but a `UINavigationBar` instead.

You can look at the iOS 5 appearance API to change the look and feel with it.

Comment: I'm seriously considering making my app available only to iOS 5. Is there anywhere I could find out about iOS version statistics? What is your opinion on this?

Comment: For a new app, with no installed base, I would definitely do it. On an existing app, you may get an occasional complaint from someone who already paid and is "left out" of the update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the moreViewController property of your tabBarController to get the more Navigation Controller (I used this on iOS7 app)

```
    UINavigationController *moreViewController = tabController.moreNavigationController;
    if(moreViewController)
    {
        [moreViewController.navigationBar setBarTintColor: [UIColor yellowColor]];
        [moreViewController.navigationBar setTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
```