# IOS - the 5th and 6th tabBar option

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my tabBar app I have a navigation bar at the top of the views. However I have more than 4 tabBars and therefore the TableView with the option to choose the others comes up.

Is there anyway to hide the navigation of the first 4 views if an end user decides to change their order?

I was kind of thinking something like this, however the if statement in this code is not right.

```
    if([[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:5])
{
    [_navBar setHidden:YES];
}
else {
    [_navBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option you might entertain if you are worried about the user re-ordering your tabs is to create a custom MoreViewController (and have no re-ordering). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9840273/741626) SO answer.

Comment: ALright I will look into that - in this case the re-ordering is not of high importance, but would be better if the end user had the option.

Answer (score 0):

After you change the order of the views in the TabBar, you should then hide the navigation bars like this

```
[self.tabBarController.viewControllers 
   enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
{
    if (index < 4)
    {
       UIViewController *vc = (UIViewController *)obj;
       [vc.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    }

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the – tabBarController:didEndCustomizingViewControllers:changed: method of UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol in a custom object and set it as the delegate of UITabBarController. Read about it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarControllerDelegate